# How to limit revision indexing to a certain date?

Tags: upsource

When creating a new project there is a message saying

> Initial indexing of history requires significant resources, while
>   having full history is usually not necessary for the purposes of code
>   review.

We have to import a large project with many revisions (10+ years) meaning that indexing part will take lots of time and resources.

Is there any way to disable the indexing or limit it to a specific date? (eg. Index revisions no older than 30 days)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, the quote you're citing comes from a Create Project wizard in Upsource and accompanies a setting that lets you do just what you're after: limit the number of days of project history to index.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I think it's worth mentioning here: since Upsource 2.0 revisions are indexed only on-demand, i.e. when one of the files is requested by the user. Most of the time, you're going to look at the latest revisions, hence only they are going to be analyzed.